# Error resolving dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

For some reason, my dependencies are being resolved to distinct API levels

[image: Error]

[image: Suggestion]

I'm very new to this and pretty confused on why I'm getting this even though I'm targeting appcompat dependency on the same API level as my `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: Don't use `:*` or `:+` for dependencies. Use only specific versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild using `compileSdkVersion 25`